# How to bind Dictionary Key and Values to telerik RadPropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, telerik

I have different things suggested in below links

https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-ti-bind-dictionary-to-radproperty-grid

but it is show count and capacity. If I change PropertySetMode property on RadPropertyGrid still no luck. Can anyone help me solve this issue ?
I have to use only MVVM pattern.

Comment: Why do you need a dictionary in your view? You can use an ordinary `ObservableCollection` or `CollectionViewSource` to show a representation of the key value pairs (e.g. as simple string). The user will mostly never operate on a key value pair directly. You would split those value in order to display each key and value e.g. inside a dedicated text box.

Comment: When your model returns a dictionary, then your view model must convert it for display inside the view.

Comment: This might be the reason the framework is not offering  a sort of ObservableDictionary. It doesn't make sense to present mapped values to the user this way. Dictionaries or hash maps in general are for code (algorithms) to speed up searching in a collection. Instead of iterating over the collection you can retrieve the value by a hashed key directly.